# Load a js image

Tags: javascript

I am writing an Android RSS reader. It uses webview to display each article. To identify the most read news I load a fake image from my server like:

```
<img src='http://example.com/update_read_count.php?article_id=1234'>
```

At the server I will increment the view counter.

Is there a way I can respond back with the number of times it has been read. Or is there a way I can update a DOM element inject this count in the page?

Comment: Are you able to use javascript/jQuery so that you can just send a get request to your server? That's definietly the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an image, the only way you could do that would be to generate an image containing the text you wanted on the server. e.g. [with this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).

If you wanted to update the DOM, you'd need to get the data in a more useful format. Using `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch the data and then returning it in JSON format would be traditional.